# Обучающая программа, по построению параллелограмма, по двум сторонам и углу

Tags: delphi, pascal

Мне нужно написать обучающую программу по построению параллелограмма по двум сторонам и углу между ними.

Написал процедуру по построению первой стороны:

```
procedure Otrezok_AD;
begin
  AD := form1.SpinEdit1.Value;
  AD := 10 * AD;
  x := form1.Image1.width div 2;
  y := form1.Image1.Height div 2;

  with form1.Image1.Canvas do
  begin
    pen.width := 3;
    pen.Style := pssolid;
    brush.Color := clblack;
    fillrect(cliprect);
    moveto(x - AD, y);
    lineto(x + AD, y);
    font.Size := 22;
    textout(x - AD - 15, y + 2, 'A');
    textout(x + AD + 3, y + 2, 'D');
  end;
  form1.Memo1.Text :=
    'Из произвольной точки А откладываем горизонтальный отрезок =' +
    inttostr(form1.SpinEdit1.Value) + 'см. Получим точку D.';
end;
```

Не могу разобраться, как выводить луч из точки А под нужным мне углом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
procedure UgolA;
  begin
  u:=form1.SpinEdit3.Value;
  a.X:=x-ad;
  a.Y:=y;
  b.X:=a.X+round(ab*cos(u*pi/180));
  b.Y:=a.Y-round(ab*sin(u*pi/180));
  with form1.Image1.Canvas do
    begin
    pen.Width:=3;
    pen.Color:=clblack;
    pen.Style:=pssolid;
    moveto(a.X,a.Y);
    lineto(b.X,b.y);
    textout(b.X-20,b.Y-25,'B');
    end;
  Form1.Memo1.Text:='При помощи транспортира,через точку А проведите прямую, под углом '+inttostr(form1.SpinEdit3.Value)+'°, длинной '+inttostr(form1.SpinEdit2.Value)+'cм. Поставьте точку B.';
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если посмотреть на картинку ниже, то очевидно что вы можете, на основании известного вам угла, рассчитать стороны треугольника и нарисовать одну из них через MoveTo() и LineTo():

[image: Синусы и косинусы.]
<sub>(источник: [mnemonica.ru](http://www.mnemonica.ru/sites/www.mnemonica.ru/files/users/1/img/sinus-cosinus.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам будет чем-то полезен код на JavaScript:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/* 
 * Рисуем линию из точки x, y длины len под 
 * углом angle
 */
function draw_line(x, y, len, angle) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    x += len * Math.cos(angle);
    y -= len * Math.sin(angle);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
}

/*
 * Рисуем параллелограм. x, y - координаты левого
 * нижнего угла параллелограма; a - сторона основания;
 * b - длина боковой стороны; angle - угол, под которым
 * рисуется боковая сторона.
 */
function draw_parallelogram(x, y, a, b, angle) {
    draw_line(x, y, b, angle);
    draw_line(x + a, y, b, angle);
    draw_line(x, y, a, 0);
    x += b * Math.cos(angle);
    y -= b * Math.sin(angle);
    draw_line(x, y, a, 0);
}

draw_parallelogram(100, 100, 200, 100, Math.PI/4); // 45 градусов
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```